# What's the proper way to add to a python list based on a condition from another Pandas column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

**Objective:** Generate a list of units where the name column includes a number

**Description:** The current code is close, but gets problematic towards the end where a list is needed and which is filled with output that meets the requested condition.

**Code:**

```
# intialise data of lists. 
info = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick 11', 'krish', 'jack_14'], 'Units':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(info) 

# Print the output. 
df

# identify row with number in name
def num_there(string):
    return any(i.isdigit() for i in string)

# create a list of all units where num_there function matches == True
for row in df['Name']:
    if num_there(row)==True:
        print(df['Units'], row)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not pretty sure that I understand what you are looking for, but you can use ```print(df['Units'].values) ``` . And if you look for all results, you can construct a list of list and then flatten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to look for any number with `\d` in the column Name and then use it to select the wanted rows of the column Units:

```
l_units = df.Units[df.Name.str.contains('\d')].tolist()
print (l_units)
[21, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas `str.contains` with `regex`:

```
df[df["Name"].str.contains('\d', regex=True)]

    Name    Units
1   nick 11 21
3   jack_14 18
```

Then:

```
list(df[df["Name"].str.contains('\d', regex=True)].Units)

[21, 18]
```